# Store data in ofstream without opening a file

Tags: c++

Is there a way to store data into a ofstream like:

```
#include <fstream>

int main() {
    std::ofstream output;
    std::ifstream input("myfile.txt");

    int a;

    for (int i=0;i<100;i++) {
        input >> a;
        output << a+1;
    }

    input.close();

    output.open("myfile.txt");
    // Save everything to the file and close it

}
```

I want to essentially change the numbers in the file ("myfile.txt") but without creating a new file. Is stdio required for this?

Answer (score 4):

You can write first to a [`ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) which is an in-memory output stream. And then write the contents into another stream, e.g.:

```
std::ostringstream in_memory_stream;

// fill in_memory_stream
// ...

// copy in_memory_stream into myfile.txt
std::ofstream file("myfile.txt");
file << in_memory_stream.rdbuf();
```

Alternatively, write to a file with a temporary name. Once the file is complete, flush it and rename it to the final name.

Comment: The temporary file method is probably best if you have the currently non-standard file system facilities. +1

Comment: @BaummitAugen I would be surprised if one did not have them. See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#rename

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin I know that should not be a problem, but as someone who writes C90 at work, I know that some people have weird constraints on what they can use. :/

Answer (score 0):

you could save the data in memory and then overwrite the old file

```
    ifstream input("myfile.txt");

    int a;
    vector<int> vin;

    for (int i=0;i<100;i++) {
        input >> a;
        vin.push_back(a+1);
    }

    input.close();
    ofstream out("myfile.txt");
    for(int i=0;i<vin.size();++i)
    {
      out<<vin[i]<<endl;
    }
```

Comment: [Why flush the stream writing every single `int`?](http://chris-sharpe.blogspot.co.uk/2016/02/why-you-shouldnt-use-stdendl.html)